# How to add a line break in LaTeX multicolumn heading?

Tags: latex, line-breaks, tabular

I have the following table in latex which is centered:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large \cellcolor{bleudefrance}\color{white}\textbf{very long sentence}}
```

How can I make the column heading "very long sentence" have a line break in between so that the column heading runs on two lines e.g.

> Very long
> Sentence

will be the column heading?

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i dont have a working example as behind a firewall

Answer (score 0):

Using the package [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), you can set the column type to allow automatic line breaks without splitting the word, as in the following minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\centering%\caption{cap}%\label{lab}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|C{\textwidth}|}{\large\textbf{%
very long sentence very long sentence very long sentence very long sentence very long sentence very long long sentence%
}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]